# compression method not supported

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am using Ionic.Zip.dll in xamarin android for unzip file , it is working in debug mode correctly , but in release mode it  is giving  following error.

'compression method not supported'

My code is below .

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(ZipFilePath))
{    zip.Password = password
     zip.ExtractAll(ExtractFilePath);
}
```

please help me.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Same file you are trying to decompress?

Comment: Actully, my zip file is compressed using chilkat library.

Comment: I imagine that's your problem then. Chillkat supports things like zip64 and self-extracting archives which may not be supported by Ionic.